# CSS Flexbox Border Radius with text-overflow: Ellipsis

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I want to apply border radius with flexbox and ellipsis on my list items and also want a `min-width` like the example below.

```
<ul>
<li style="flex: 1 1;"><span>A</span></li>
<li style="flex: 2 2;"><span>this is a pretty long text that will overflow the parent container</span></li>
<li style="flex: 1 1;"><span>C</span></li>
```

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

span {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0em 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

**Here's the example**
http://jsfiddle.net/mnk/kah0bn6o/1/

The goal is to apply the border radius on the element with the ellipsis applied

Comment: Also apply the border-radius to the `<li>`s. You can keep the spans this way.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it work would be to remove the `<span>` tags. Put everything into the `<li>`s.

Try this:

**HTML** (removed `span` tags)

```
<ul>
    <li style="flex: 1 1;">A</li>
    <li style="flex: 2 2;">this is a pretty long text that will overflow the parent
                          container</li>
    <li style="flex: 1 1;">C</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {     
    padding: 0em 1em;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kah0bn6o/5/

Alternatively, you could keep the `span`s and simply apply the `border-radius` rule to both `span` and `li` elements.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kah0bn6o/7/

Comment: nice point but the span is there to only wrap the word the "A" width should be 20px maximum

Comment: then simply adjust the `flex` rule you have in your inline style: `flex: 0 1 20px`... http://jsfiddle.net/kah0bn6o/6/

Comment: add a copy of the `border-radius` to the `li` and you're done: http://jsfiddle.net/kah0bn6o/7/

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without the span then you can just move all the styles on to `li` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/f6Lgbtre/

```
li {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 0em 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
}
```

and

```
<li style="flex: 1 1;">A</li>
```